# What is the best way to save a task entity by associating it with the user it belongs to?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

Task Class

```
@Entity
public class Task {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String title;
private String text;
private boolean done;
}
```

User class, which contains the tasks

```
@Entity
public class TodolistUser {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String login;
private String password;

@Autowired
@ElementCollection
private List<Task> tasks;
}
```

and service

```
@Service
public class TodolistUserService {
    @Autowired
    private TodolistUserRepository repository;
}
```

> How could I persist a task relating it to the user it belongs to, using the repository that extends from JpaRepository?

Comment: Are you sure about the class Task being an entity and not embeddable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to change certain things :

Task Class

```
@Embedabble               // or @Entity if you want to use @OneToMany in TodoListUser
public class Task {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String title;
private String text;
private boolean done;
}
```

User class, which contains the tasks

```
@Entity
public class TodolistUser {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String login;
private String password;

@Autowired  // Not Recommended
@ElementCollection
private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>(); // Or other implementations
}


@Service
public class TodolistUserService {
    @Autowired
    private TodolistUserRepository repository;

    public void addFoo(TodoListUser foo){
repository.save(foo);
}



}
```

Comment: There are some disadvantages to using Embeddable. You can never select an Embedable by itself, so if you want a detail page for each Task, you have to load all tasks. Although ElementCollections are lazy loaded, you have to load all or none, so pagination is effectively out of the question. @Embedable was fine, when you could embed a single object (reusable code through composition), but I believe the ElementCollection is taking it too far, and causes new JPA developers to solve problems the wrong way.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek OP has used ElementCollection for mapping so I suggested using the Embeddable . Also the naming and structure of classes suggest that class Task doesnt need to be an entity as it's existence is purely dependent on the TodoListUser(Just like a class Address with class User). Also i have mentioned an alternative in the comment.